# Image handlernot loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got 2 handlers & did the same thing to the other handler because im trying to display image on both form on gridview. For some reason , one of the handler doesnt load. May i know where i should look into?

I checked the browser but it returns a id Handler1.ashx?id=1, meaning its working but its not running the Handler1

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="100" Width="100" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#    "Handler1.ashx?id=" + Eval("ID")  %>' />
```

Hope can someone can advice on this. THanks :D

Comment: show your webConfig, HttpHandler codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recreate the file then copy paste the codes over. Might be a VS bug